# JavaScript: How to redirect a page after validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to redirect a page after validation. I have the ff. EXAMPLE:

form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<p><span style="width:180px">Username: </span><input type="text" name="username" id='un'></p>
<p><span style="width:180px">Password: </span><input type="password" name="password" id='pw'></p>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function checkform(){
    if(document.getElementById("un").value == 'jayem30' && document.getElementById("pw").value == 'jayem' ){
        alert("Login Successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
    }else{
        alert("Access denied. Valid username and password is required.");
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried this but it does not redirect to google.com. Many thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting redirect in a timeout. Works like a charm

```
setTimeout(function() {window.location = "http://www.google.com/" });
```

By the way, instead of

```
onsubmit="return checkform(this);"
```

use

```
onsubmit="return(checkform())"
```

because IE doesn't like when you ommit ( and ).

Answer (score 0):

try document.location.href instead of window.location

Comment: Should be window.location.href

Comment: document.location doesn't work in all browsers. window.location does.

Comment: Yes I agree. Use window.location instead of document.location for cross browser functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this method to redirect page after validation.

syntax:

```
window.location.assign("url")
```

example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function checkform(){

    if(document.getElementById("un").value == 'jayem30' && document.getElementById("pw").value == 'jayem' ){
        alert("Login Successful");
        window.location.assign("http://www.google.com/")
    }else{
        alert("Access denied. Valid username and password is required.");
    }
}
</script>
```

This is a working method.